# Member function self defined Type returns 'does not name a type' error in C++

Tags: c++, oop

Inside of my class, I declare a type with the 'using' keyword, "bigvalue_t" and attempt to create a function that returns the same type (to_vector). I get returned this error through gcc:

```
 g++ -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -c bigint.cpp
 bigint.cpp:45:1: error: ‘bigvalue_t’ does not name a type
 bigvalue_t bigint::to_vector (string& strval) {
 ^
```

Here is the class from my header file:

```
class bigint {
  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const bigint&);
private:
  long long_value {};
  using unumber = unsigned long;
  using digit_t = unsigned char;
  using bigvalue_t = vector<digit_t>;
  bool negative;
  bigvalue_t big_value;
  string to_string (unumber& num);
  bigvalue_t to_vector (string& strval);
  using quot_rem = pair<bigint,bigint>;
  friend quot_rem divide (const bigint&, const bigint&);
  friend void multiply_by_2 (unumber&);
  friend void divide_by_2 (unumber&);
public:

  //
  // Ensure synthesized members are genrated.
  //
  bigint() = default;
  bigint (const bigint&) = default;
  bigint (bigint&&) = default;
  bigint& operator= (const bigint&) = default;
  bigint& operator= (bigint&&) = default;
  ~bigint() = default;

  //
  // Extra ctors to make bigints.
  //
  bigint (const long);
  bigint (const string&);
```

Here is my constructor and the function in question:

```
bigint::bigint (long that): long_value (that) {
   using digit_t = unsigned char;
   using bigvalue_t = vector<digit_t>;
   if (that < 0) this->negative = true;
   else this->negative = false;
   unumber that_value = that;
   string that_str = to_string (that_value);
   bigvalue_t bignum = to_vector (that_str);
   }

bigvalue_t bigint::to_vector (string& strval) {
   digit_t digi;
   bigvalue_t digivec;
   for (auto it = strval.rbegin(); it != rend; ++i) {
       digi = strval[it];
   digivec.push_back(digi);
   }
  return digivec;
}
```

Any ideas as to whats going on would be much appreciated! It doesn't seem to pick up my type definition. I was allowed to use my other self defined variable "unumber" in an earlier method without fault so this has me scratching my head.

Comment: Use `bigint::bigvalue_t bigint::to_vector (string& strval)` or `auto bigint::to_vector (string& strval) -> bigvalue_t`

Comment: `using` directives are only valid in the scope where they appear.

Comment: Excellent, Piotr's answer resolved my issues with scope.

Comment: Shame he posted his answer as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As state in comment, use

```
bigint::bigvalue_t bigint::to_vector (string& strval)
{
    // body
}
```

or since C++11

```
auto bigint::to_vector (string& strval) -> bigvalue_t
{
    // body
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  Both of these resolved my scope problem.  The C++11 revision seems handy.